# "missing values in object" when using caret::train function

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation, r-caret, caret

I ran into this error when I was trying to use the train function in {caret} package to do a 100-fold cv for a regression model. The codes I executed are as follows:

```
#read the dataset and convert columns to factors
data<-read.csv("synchronic_dataset_full.csv")
data<-as.data.frame(unclass(data), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

#cross-validation using train() in {caret}
set.seed(527)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(data$realization, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- data [ inTraining,]
testing  <- data [-inTraining,]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 100)

regression_fit <- train(realization ~ (1|verb/VerbSense) + 
                                      (1|Corpus) + 
                                      Variety + 
                                      Register +
                                      FollowVerb +      
                                      z.WeightRatio + 
                                      ThemeConcreteness +
                                      PrimeTypeCoarse +
                                      RecPron +
                                      z.RecThematicity +
                                      ThemeDef +
                                      z.RecHeadFrequency +
                                      RecHumaness +
                                      RecComplexity +
                                      ThemeComplexity +
                                      z.TTR +
                                      Variety*
                                      (RecComplexity +
                                      RecPron) +
                                      Register *
                                      ThemeConcreteness, 
                                      data = training, 
                                      method = "glm",
                                      metric = "Accuracy",
                                      trControl = fitControl)
regression_fit
```

And the error says:

> Error in na.fail.default(list(realization = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : missing values in object

I checked the dataset and I am sure it contains no missing/NA values. I also attempted to solve the problem by adding an extra line of `na.action=na.exclude` after `trControl=FitControl`, and it doesn't help. The dataset can be accessed in [this](https://osf.io/4pmh3/) OSF page (note: please kindly delete it after using, as it's contains sensitive unpublished & un-peer-reviewed information).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parenthesis around `(1|...)` in the model formula.
Another possibility is that `|` does not apply to factors, which is the case here I guess.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Both (1|verb/VerbSense) and (1|Corpus) constitute the random effect component of the model, so the problem is that if I remove the parenthesis the predictor will become a fixed effect predictor instead of a random one, which is undesirable for the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the issue and obtained relevant results using the following codes:

```
set.seed(527)
for (i in 1:100){
  Train <- createDataPartition(data$realization, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
  training <- data[Train, ]
  testing <- data[-Train, ]
  mod_fit <- glmer (realization ~ (1|verb/VerbSense) + 
                                  (1|Corpus) + 
                                  Variety + 
                                  Register +
                                  FollowVerb +      
                                  z.WeightRatio + 
                                  ThemeConcreteness +
                                  PrimeTypeCoarse +
                                  RecPron +
                                  z.RecThematicity +
                                  ThemeDef +
                                  z.RecHeadFrequency +
                                  RecHumaness +
                                  RecComplexity +
                                  ThemeComplexity +
                                  z.TTR +
                                  Variety*
                                  (RecComplexity +
                                  RecPron) +
                                  Register *
                                  ThemeConcreteness, data=training, family="binomial")
  pred = predict(mod_fit, newdata=testing,allow.new.levels = TRUE)
  predictions.cat=ifelse(pred>0.5,"ThemeFirst", "RecipientFirst")
  predictions.cat=as.factor(predictions.cat)
  result=confusionMatrix(data=predictions.cat, testing$realization)
  print(result$overall[1])
}
```

As the problem has been solved, and considering that the dataset is still under construction, the material in the OSF page link has been removed.